# Remove nested links in a text using regex/php

Tags: php, html, regex

I have some texts with many links and some of them have nested links. I was trying to create a regex to remove any link inside a link anchor leaving the anchor text.

My idea was using regex to find all text anchors and replace them with the same text with tags removed. Howerver I can't achive it.

Example:

```
<p>Any text <a href="#">a correct link</a> more text <a href="#">some <a href="#">word</a>.</a><p>
```

Expected result

```
<p>Any text <a href="#">a correct link</a> more text <a href="#">some word.</a><p>
```

What I was trying is what it follows:

```
$pattern="/<a.*>([a-zA-Z ].*)<\/a>/";
preg_match_all ($pattern , $text, $matches);
foreach($matches as $match)
{
    $text=str_replace($match[0],strip_tags($match[0],'<b>'),$text);
}
```

Comment: What regex did you try? What did you accomplish? Have you tried using regex101.com ? Remember, stackoverflow is here to help you fix problems, not to write the code for you.

Comment: I've edited the question with the last piece of code I have been trying,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've resolved in that way

```
    $pattern = '/<a.*>([a-zA-Z0-9&#;\s]*<a.*>[a-zA-Z0-9&#;\s]*<\/a>[a-zA-Z0-9&#;\s]*)<\/a>/m';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach($matches as $match)
{

    $text = str_replace($match[1], strip_tags($match[1]), $text);

}

return $text;
```

Honestly, I don't thing it is the best way, however it works in the most of cases.

Thanks for your tips Mohammad Bagheri.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
$pattern = '/<a.*>.*(<a.*>(.*)<\/a>(.*))<\/a>/m';
$text = '<p>Any text <a href="#">a correct link</a> more text <a href="#">some <a href="#">word</a>.</a><p>';

preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

$matches = $matches[0];
$to_search = $matches[1];
unset($matches[0], $matches[1]);

$to_replace = '';
foreach($matches AS $match)
    $to_replace .= $match;

$str = str_replace($to_search, $to_replace, $text);
```

I hope this helps.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your halp but it just works in the example, if text has more links it has problems.
For instance with this text:
<p>Any text <a href="#">a correct link</a> more text <a href="#">some <a href="#">word</a>.</a> other <a href="#">Next link</a><p>